# Stop particles from dying for a few frames?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm trying to animate a blowball (puffy dandelion). I created two particle systems, one starting with all particles (the seeds) placed onto the central knob and then, over the space of 300 frames, randomly dying, until at the end of the animation there are no more particles/seeds left on the knob.
Some frames into the dying particles, another particle system starts emitting (flying seeds), stopping also after 300 frames, therefore giving the illusion the seeds really take off.

This all works nicely so far.

But now, I'd like to give the illusion of little wind gusts. For the flying seeds, I just copied the particle system and changed the start and end accordingly. 
But this won't work for the still attached seeds.

If they all died out at frame 300, how could there be anymore flying seeds in frames 301 and following?

If they last until end of animation, why do seeds go missing without flying seeds around?

if I copy the particle system and let the copy start at frame 301, I get a miraculously regrown blowball.

So I'd need to somehow stop my attached seeds from dying for, say, two to four seconds, during which the flying seeds clear up and float away, and restart dying after this pause.

Anybody any idea how to do this?

Comment: Using texture in the flying particles you can limit the force effect by offsetting the texture coordinates. So by animating the coordinates offset, you can achieve the effect that wind gusts fly off the seeds.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm fairly new to Blender and can't quite follow...